# Define a logger with insertion operator to empty

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

**What I am trying to do:**

My project uses [CuteLogger](http://dept2.github.io/CuteLogger/) for logging. It is extensive, and among others runs on some small embedded platforms. As the project has grown, complications required a lot of debugging and logging, and it is now running slow. 
We have a large number of `LOG_TRACE` which were our way of removing the log but keeping it for future reference, and it may be a cause of slowness. 
Of course it will need profiling. But as an idea, I would like to try, possibly temporary, to remove only the `LOG_TRACE` in release.

Original: (similar for all log levels)

```
#define LOG_TRACE   CuteMessageLogger(loggerInstance(), Logger::Trace,   __FILE__, __LINE__, Q_FUNC_INFO).write
```

My thinking: only for this log level:

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
#define LOG_TRACE   CuteMessageLogger(loggerInstance(), Logger::Trace,   __FILE__, __LINE__, Q_FUNC_INFO).write
#else
#define LOG_TRACE(fmt,arg...)  ((void)0)
#endif
```

**Problem:**

`CuteLogger` is smarter than me, and has the ability to use insertion operators - which are used almost exclusively throughout the projects. So, I am getting an error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'void' and 'QString')
LOG_TRACE() << message;
```

How can I define my logger to nothing, covering the insertion operator case as well ?

Comment: The logger I implemented on an embedded system was two components.  Component 1 is the logger, as a separate task.  Component 2 is the interface to the logger that all the other tasks can use.  Basically, the interface sends a message to the logger, containing the data.  The logger task is always pending on the mailbox.  When the logger wakes up, it processes the message in its mailbox, then sleeps until another message is received.  The messages are stored in RAM until they are output.  This helps reduce the overhead on the main system and allows the OS to schedule the loggerr as a low prior.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That sounds interesting, I will "log" the idea to improve our logging, though it would not solve the problem of the LOG_TRACE existing and using the system resources with its overhead.